# Why can I remove the code navArgument without problem when I use Navigating with arguments in JetPack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Jetpack Compose Navigation.

The Code A is from the [article](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#3). It works well.

I can't understand fully what the code `navArgument` means. I find the Code B which is removed the code `navArgument` can work well too.

What does the code `navArgument` mean?

**Code A**

```
val accountsName = RallyScreen.Accounts.name
NavHost(...) {
    ...
    composable(
        "$accountsName/{name}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("name") {
                // Make argument type safe
                type = NavType.StringType
            }
        )
    ) { entry -> // Look up "name" in NavBackStackEntry's arguments
        val accountName = entry.arguments?.getString("name")
        ..
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
val accountsName = RallyScreen.Accounts.name
NavHost(...) {
    ...
    composable(
        "$accountsName/{name}"       
    ) { entry -> // Look up "name" in NavBackStackEntry's arguments
        val accountName = entry.arguments?.getString("name")
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args):

> By default, all arguments are parsed as strings. You can specify another type by using the arguments parameter to set a type

So the second option works, and it can be used if all your parameters are of string type.

`navArgument` should be used when the default string type is not appropriate for your parameters, and you need it to be int, optional string, etc.